Storing my API Keys in a PHP file inside of my "public_html" Hostgator folder for my website: Is this secure? Or can prying eyes access its contents?
I know the conventional wisdom is, never store API keys in the frontend -- instead always store this on the server-side. My programming / web development up to this point has all been pretty simple stuff, to the degree that I've never really needed to use secret API keys or info like this that needs to be hidden. Everything has basically just been HTML / CSS / JS.
My initial thinking was -- "ok, store it on the backend means, like when i have a database and there's that code that runs when you send a request to the database, i can store the API keys inside of there, since that's like a hidden black box that people can't access."
Now it appears another option is, I can have other filetypes on my Hostgator website, where those filetypes will remain hidden/secured, to where nobody can access the actual interiors of the files. So in my websites public_html HTML/CSS/JS frontend files, I could send Javascript requests to those PHP files, and use the outputs as needed -- but nobody could access and actually see the contents of those PHP files.
Is my understanding of how this all works correct?

If Javascript can request the contents of those files, then they’re public by definition.

The PHP script isn't written to output the API key under any conditions though. Maybe I'm missing something here, but my understanding is you can execute PHP scripts, pass inputs to it, and read/handle its outputs via server-side Javascript, but there's no way the user can fully read/output the entire full contents of that PHP script. It's not like the PHP script outputs the API key back to the Javascript or anything or prints it to the console log; the API keys are in the script and the code that accesses those website APIs all runs via the PHP script. What am I missing here?

Yes. If it’s the PHP making the request using some API key, and it only returns the resulting data of that to the frontend, sure, that works.

Gotcha, thanks for clarifying. That is the plan. I can't do API requests via Javascript anyway, it gets blocked by the websites under the NO CORS policy. So I'm basically hardcoding the API keys into a PHP file, running the API requests inside that same PHP file, and all the JS does is run the PHP scripts, pass some user-supplied inputs into it, and read back/handle the outputs. Some are recommending extra steps like storing the API keys in some other secondary file, or hosting the PHP file in another location, but none of that seems strictly necessary based on what I'm doing.

typo -- my earlier reply should have said "client-side Javascript", not "server-side Javascript"

As per what @ADyson suggested, it is better to store such data in a separate files. Usually in big projects that uses frameworks, you store such api keys in .env and ignore them from your source control. For vanilla php, you can try this package on how to load .env file: https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv

It's arguably better for configurability to store variables such as keys in a separate file and load them at runtime - that way you can deploy your code in different environments, and with different key values etc, without needing two different copies of the code base.
It also keeps such keys out of your source control repository, meaning there's one less place for them to leak from.
But yes if you've hard coded the API key as a variable into a PHP script it won't ever be shown to an end user, because php code never is - unless your server is seriously misconfigured of course.

"unless your server is seriously misconfigured of course."
How would I know if this is the case, or if I'm at risk of making a change that causes this to happen? The website hosting is through Hostgator, and really the main steps I do when creating a new website is: 1) purchase a domain; 2) change the nameservers to match the main base website; 3) set the new URLs up as "add-on domains" (basically letting me create a lot more websites under the main hosting server I use -- pretty sure that's how it works). What specific files or settings, if poked around with, would cause server issues?

@king_anton How would I know if this is the case...you'd know because if you visited a PHP file's URL from that server in the browser it would display the PHP code on the screen (instead of executing it and displaying the executed script's output). And unless you seriously mess about with the Apache config (or whatever webserver is in use here) without having a clue what you're doing, it'd be pretty difficult to do that. If you're using a shared hosting provider, you won't even have sufficient rights to access those configuration settings, so there's nothing to worry about on that point.

...the only other way to really muck it up I guess would be to accidentally rename a .php file as something which isn't executed, e.g. .txt, even though it actually contains code with sensitive data in it. But if you're testing and deploying your code locally and then uploading it to the server when it's good and working - as you should, if you have any kind of proper development and testing process - then the chances of that kind of silly mistake are fairly low. (Editing/renaming files once they're already on the server would be something you do very rarely, if ever.)
